# Remove IE8 extra padding from TD element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 I get extra padding in for the `td` elements.

Here is my `html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="actionDiv" width="100%" align="center" style="display:none;"></div>
        <table class="background" width="100%">
            <tr width="100%">
                <td align="center"><div id="new"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button1" id="button1" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="save"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button1" id="button2" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="savenew"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button3" id="button3" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="saveback"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button4" id="button4" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="select"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button5" id="button5" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="modify"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button6" id="button6" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="view"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button7" id="button7" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="copy"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button8" id="button8" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="delete"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button9" id="button9" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="report1"><input type="button" class="button" value="Report1" id="report1" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id=""><input type="button" class="button" value="report2" id="Report2"/></td>
                <td align="right" width="100%"><div id="back"><input type="button" class="button" value="Back" id="Button10" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `css` file

```
.background {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 1px;
}

input.button {
    background-color: #7B9978;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff; /*width: 100px;*/
    overflow:visible;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    height: 18px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

I have achieved to shorten the input elements not to fill the `td` element, however as

as you can see on the image

[image]

there is a significant padding between the buttons because of the `td` elements. How could I remove this padding (without using DOCTYPE) in IE8?

In FF it looks like this (this is how it should look like in IE8 too)

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using divs unless you really have to show something in table format. 

PS Strict doctype seems to solve many problems in IE

Comment: Use a CSS reset like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or HTML5 Boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/. And is there are a reason for using a table-based layout?

Comment: You have *a list of buttons*. An `<ul>/<li>` with `float: left;` will work better, both optically and semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on different allocation of columns when conflicting requirements are imposed (the last cell has width="100%"). To avoid this, change the `div` elements enclosing `input` elements to `span` elements and place them, except the first one, into the first cell of the row.

Comment: this is a good idea. The only thing that is left is that the last button has to be aligned to right and if I apply foat:right to it, it gets rendered on a new line. But this can be fixed by putting this span as the first one in the div.

Comment: If you put the last button in a cell of its own, you can just set text-align: right on the cell, without any floating.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE8 to test your code, but this usually does the trick for me:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Also, TD will have padding as default style.

```
td, table, tr {
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this solution does not solve my problem. There is still padding between the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can control

CSS

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

HTML
 you can change width and adjust based on your need.

```
   <table class="background" width="100%">
        <tr>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="new"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button1" id="button1" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="save"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button1" id="button2" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="savenew"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button3" id="button3" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="saveback"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button4" id="button4" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="select"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button5" id="button5" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="modify"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button6" id="button6" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="view"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button7" id="button7" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="copy"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button8" id="button8" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="delete"><input type="button" class="button" value="Button9" id="button9" readonly="readonly"/></div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id="report1"><input type="button" class="button" value="Report1" id="report1" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
                <td align="center" width="4%"><div id=""><input type="button" class="button" value="report2" id="Report2"/></div></td>
                <td align="right" width="56%"><div id="back"><input type="button" class="button" value="Back" id="Button10" readonly="readonly"/> </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```